# how to get contentDetails part from youtube video list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i am working on youtube api v3 and want to show each video with duration in list.
here is my code but when i run this code it gives me error

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error 400
>   contentDetails : unknownPart' in
>   /home/whatcove/public_html/youtube/youtube_v3/yt/vendor/madcoda/php-youtube-api/lib/Madcoda/Youtube.php:364
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/whatcove/public_html/youtube/youtube_v3/yt/vendor/madcoda/php-youtube-api/lib/Madcoda/Youtube.php(145):
>   Madcoda\Youtube->decodeList('{\n "error": {\n ...') #1
>   /home/whatcove/public_html/youtube/youtube_v3/yt/vendor/madcoda/php-youtube-api/lib/Madcoda/Youtube.php(77):
>   Madcoda\Youtube->searchAdvanced(Array) #2
>   /home/whatcove/public_html/youtube/youtube_v3/yt/index.php(12):
>   Madcoda\Youtube->search('leela movie') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/whatcove/public_html/youtube/youtube_v3/yt/vendor/madcoda/php-youtube-api/lib/Madcoda/Youtube.php
>   on line 364"

```
    public function search($q, $maxResults = 10)
{
    $params = array(
        'q' => $q,
        'part' => 'id, snippet, contentDetails',
        'maxResults' => $maxResults
    );
    return $this->searchAdvanced($params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'search' endpoint does not have a contentDetails part; nor can you retrieve video durations from the 'search' endpoint. Rather, it's used to get minimal information (think of the metaphor of search results) and offer the most possible filters, and then when a video is selected, you can use the videoId to hit the 'videos' endpoint (where you have much more info returned but less possible filters, so it really can't be used for searching).